# Copilot is encountering temporary issues

Tags: github, github-copilot

I'm using GitHub Copilot for VScode. I work for corporate, my company connect internet through proxy. I already config proxy in vscode, here is my settings.json file

```
"http.proxy": "http://my-proxy:PORT",
"http.proxyStrictSSL": false,
```

When I try copilot, it encounter a problem: Copilot is encountering temporary issues. The output of copilot is still success, but I'm not getting suggest code

```
[DEBUG] [proxy-socket-factory] [2023-08-17T09:12:46.783Z] Attempting to establish connection to proxy
[DEBUG] [proxy-socket-factory] [2023-08-17T09:12:46.791Z] Socket Connect returned status code,200
[DEBUG] [proxy-socket-factory] [2023-08-17T09:12:46.791Z] Successfully established tunneling connection to proxy
[DEBUG] [proxy-socket-factory] [2023-08-17T09:12:47.476Z] Attempting to establish connection to proxy
[DEBUG] [proxy-socket-factory] [2023-08-17T09:12:47.552Z] Socket Connect returned status code,200
[DEBUG] [proxy-socket-factory] [2023-08-17T09:12:47.552Z] Successfully established tunneling connection to proxy
[INFO] [default] [2023-08-17T09:12:47.879Z] [fetchCompletions] engine https://copilot-proxy.githubusercontent.com/v1/engines/copilot-codex
[DEBUG] [proxy-socket-factory] [2023-08-17T09:12:47.880Z] Attempting to establish connection to proxy
[DEBUG] [proxy-socket-factory] [2023-08-17T09:12:47.920Z] Socket Connect returned status code,200
[DEBUG] [proxy-socket-factory] [2023-08-17T09:12:47.920Z] Successfully established tunneling connection to proxy
[INFO] [default] [2023-08-17T09:12:48.367Z] request.response: [https://copilot-proxy.githubusercontent.com/v1/engines/copilot-codex/completions] took 487 ms
```

I try reinstall Copilot but it's doesn't work